# Why is my simple PHP query returning duplicate values?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When I use PHP to do a simple query on a MySQL database, the object being returned holds duplicate values.

This is the PHP code where I query the database:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM names';
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

$data = array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($data, $row);
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

The returning JSON object (being outputted by the Chrome console through Javascript) is as follows:

```
[{"0": "1", "id": "1", "1": "Jeff", "name": "Jeff"},
 {"0": "2", "id": "2", "1": "Andrew", "name": "Andrew"}]
```

Each value is listed twice: once as its correct column name and once as its column name's index. Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: can you please print_r($row); inside your while?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_array()` returns both a numerical and asssociative array of the resultset. You need to use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` to get just the associative array.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    array_push($data, $row);
}
```